# node.js osmesa-webgl install error

Tags: npm, gyp

After npm install osmesa-webgl I got this Error. During installation everything seems ok (compiling and creating libraries.. etc.). After this error everything is is erased so I can´t analyze files. This is stack from console.

```
In file included from /root/.node-gyp/0.12.7/src/node.h:61:0,
             from ../src/common.h:11,
             from ../src/webgl.h:11,
             from ../src/bindings.cc:9: 
/root/.node-gyp/0.12.7/deps/v8/include/v8.h:2012:25: note: static v8::Local<v8::Integer> v8::Integer::New(v8::Isolate*, int32_t)
   static Local<Integer> New(Isolate* isolate, int32_t value);
                     ^
/root/.node-gyp/0.12.7/deps/v8/include/v8.h:2012:25: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
webgl.target.mk:90: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/webgl
src/bindings.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/webgl/src/bindings.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/var/www/trider/render/node_modules/osmesa-webgl/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/trider/render/node_modules/osmesa-webgl
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "osmesa-webgl"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That module will only work with Node 0.10 - you have the wrong version.

I have a fork with updates here: https://github.com/fixplz/osmesa-webgl

(But the dev dependencies will still not work with 0.12)